# Outlook 2011 Public Folder Calendar

Tags: exchange, outlook

Our public folders are 100% migrated to Exchange 2013. Outlook 2011 (14.3.6) can see the public folders, and on a mail-enabled folder can see items/updates; however, subscribed calendars are empty. (Not empty on windows clients)

Is there a way our Mac users can get this public folder calendar?

**EDIT:**
As a workaround, I have set up a dummy exchange user. This user's calendar has the same info as the public folder calendar. (The secretary who updates the public folder calendar has agreed to copy the changes to the dummy user's calendar.)

Outlook 2011 users just open the shared calendar and it displays properly.

If anyone is aware of a utility/script/program that copies changes from a public folder calendar to a user calendar? It would be a one-way sync.

Comment: Found this and since O365 now uses exch2013 it might be the same issue. http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/153/t/168702.aspx?PageIndex=2.  That said, when you subscribed did you then see if they showed up in the Calendars view and not just in the folder view?

Comment: Yes, it is listed in the calendar view. You can uncheck it and check it, but it doesn't update. I am about to update this question with our current workaround.

Comment: I should also include that the bottom right info shows that it tries to update, then goes away after 3 seconds. The calendar remains blank.

Comment: Just fyi, based on your workaround, most online are stating to use a Resource mailbox now instead of a public folder calendar.  Similar to what you are doing to some extent but a resource mailbox and no PF at all.

Comment: @TheCleaner If you restate your above post as an answer, I will mark it. We have gone this route and are happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fyi, based on your workaround, most online are stating to use a Resource mailbox now instead of a public folder calendar. Similar to what you are doing to some extent but a resource mailbox and no PF at all.

It would make sense, since PF technically are supposed to go away "someday"...